# IN SQL How do I get the full decimal value to display for each record and stop the figures rounding up?

Tags: sql-server

Code to create table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Currencies](
        [Currency_ID1] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
        [Currency_Type] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
        [Exchange_Rate] [decimal](10) NOT NULL,
        [Date_Modified] [date] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Currency_ID1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Currency_ID1] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
```

Employee table insert:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Currencies] ([Currency_ID1], [Currency_Type], [Exchange_Rate],[Date_Modified]) VALUES ('C0000001', 'EUR-Euro', 0.73516, '2014-5-11');

INSERT [dbo].[Currencies] ([Currency_ID1], [Currency_Type], [Exchange_Rate],[Date_Modified]) VALUES ('C0000002', 'USD-US-Dollar', 1.00000, '2014-5-11');

INSERT [dbo].[Currencies] ([Currency_ID1], [Currency_Type], [Exchange_Rate],[Date_Modified]) VALUES ('C0000003', 'GBP-British-Pound', 0.59833, '2014-5-11');

INSERT [dbo].[Currencies] ([Currency_ID1], [Currency_Type], [Exchange_Rate],[Date_Modified]) VALUES ('C0000004', 'JPY-Japanese-Dollar ',101.639, '2014-5-11');

INSERT [dbo].[Currencies] ([Currency_ID1], [Currency_Type], [Exchange_Rate],[Date_Modified]) VALUES ('C0000005', 'AUD-Australian-Dollar', 1.07422, '2014-5-11');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the decimal digit while creating the table

Like this

```
[Exchange_Rate] [decimal](10,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[decimal](10,5)` instead of `[decimal](10)`

The 10,5 will create a decimal value with up to ten digits and 5 of them will be used to store numbers after the decimal point. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx